# HTML Button not Submitting Every Time

Tags: php, html, ajax, redirect

Everything works perfectly except the submit button typically takes three to four times before it works. So I'll have the necessary cid number, plug it into the form, and hit submit. It might work the first time, but it also might take me seven attempts. I've got a bit of a deadline on this thing, and I have no idea how to even go about troubleshooting this so any help at all would be hugely appreciated!

So I've got this form:

```
<form action="" onsubmit="redirect()">
    <input type="text" name="val1" id="val1" placeholder="CID (ten digits)">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Which triggers this javascript function:

```
function redirect() {
    var userID = document.getElementById("val1").value;
    var userID = userID.replace(/-/g, "");
    //alert(userID);
    //var userID = "9183179265";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: './getNetworkType.php',
        data: "userID=" + userID,
        success: function(data) {
            //alert(data);
            if(data.indexOf("Search") > -1) {
                //alert(data.substr(data.length - 10));
                window.location = "http://jumpsixdashboard.com/Reporting/display_search.php?cid=" + data.substr(data.length - 10);
            }
            else {
                //alert(data.substr(data.length - 10));
                window.location = "http://jumpsixdashboard.com/Reporting/display_report.php?cid=" + data.substr(data.length - 10);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Which executes this script:

```
<?php
$val1 = $_POST['userID'];

$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM account_type WHERE cid ='" . $val1 . "'";

$result3 = $mysqli->query($sql3);

if ($result3->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row3["network"];
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is in your function onsubmit.

You should try something like this.

Set ID to form to example "myForm". Remove `onsubmit` from Form.

And add this code. This should send data successfull and avoid the submit that you don't won't.

```
$("#myForm").submit(function() {
  redirect();
  return false; // this avoid submit.
});
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much! If you have the time, i'm pretty curious to know how it worked though?